# Azure cannot create SendGrid account - required AAD tenant information is missing

Tags: azure, sendgrid

when i try to create new SendGrid account in azure, i always get this error message:

```
message: User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 
You cannot purchase reservation because required AAD tenant information is missing. Please ask your tenant admin to fill this form: https://aka.ms/orgprofile
```

When i try suggestet url (https://aka.ms/orgprofile) i get this error and no form is shown:

```
AADSTS900440: Requests to tenants hosted in the public cloud are not supported on USGov endpoints. This user must sign into https://login.microsoftonline.com instead of https://login.microsoftonline.us. The application must send the user to the right login endpoint, usually by hosting two versions of the site (e.g. portal.azure.us and portal.azure.com)
```

I tried to fill all possible information in our Azure Tenant and in our Organization settings and everything i can fill, is correctly filled.

Does anybody know, how to fix this issue?